# Why won't my ajax AutoSave work?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using a script found on this page: http://jetlogs.org/2007/11/11/auto-saving-with-jquery/ to autosave a form I have. I'm only trying to save the textarea for the form. Here's the relevant code:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){           
            autosave();
        });

        function autosave()
        {
            var t = setTimeout("autosave()", 5000);

            var comments = $("#comments").val();

            if (comments.length > 0)
            {
                $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "autosave.php",
                    data: "rubric_id=" + <?php echo $rubricid ?> + "&student_id=" + <?php echo $studentid ?> + "&comments=" + comments,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(message)
                    {   
                        $("#autosave_status").empty().append(message);
                    }
                });
            }
        } 
        </script> 
</head>
<body>
<div id="autosave_status"></div>
<form action='assess.php?student=146&rubric=19' method='POST'>
<textarea id="elm1" name="comments" rows="15" cols="80" style="width: 80%">
</form>
</body>
```

And here's the PHP:

```
<?php
//include DB configuration file
  include "../../signout/database.php";


$comments = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comments']);
$rubric_id = (int)$_POST['rubric_id'];
$student_id = (int)$_POST['student_id'];



//save contents to database
$sql = "UPDATE rubrics_comments SET comments = '$comments' WHERE studentid = '$student_id' AND rubricid='$rubric_id'";
mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
echo $sql;



//output timestamp
echo 'Saved';

?>
```

It seems almost as though the ajax isn't even working, since I'm not seeing any display changes or error messages on the page where the form is located.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to debug with Firebug?

Comment: I have FireBug installed but I have no idea how to use it to debug. Any tips?

Comment: press `F12` and see if there are any errors

Answer (score 5):

your textarea has an id of elm1

```
<textarea id="elm1" name="comments" rows="15" cols="80" style="width: 80%">
```

but your trying to access it by

```
$("#comments")
```

change to

```
$("#elm1")
```

or

```
$("[name=comments]")
```

Comment: Agh! I'm blind. Thank you sir! I will accept the answer once it lets me. :)

Comment: No problem, You should look into using firebug or chrome's developer tools. These types of error always happen but they are really simple to catch once you get familiar with those tools.

Answer (score 1):

Your textarea's id is not "comments". And you're using an id selector `$("#id");`

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

change

```
 var comments = $("#comments").val();
```

to

```
 var comments = $("#elm1").val();
```

And close your textarea element:

```
</textarea>
```